# Why doesn't my code correctly update the jtextpane font colour?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

```
Font displayFont = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 18);
        WindowManager.getInstance().getConsoleWindow().getTextArea().setFont(displayFont);
        WindowManager.getInstance().getConsoleWindow().getTextArea().setForeground(Color.BLUE);
```

The above is my code snippet responsible for changing the properties of the text in my jtextpane when I click a button. The text correctly updates to become larger and bold however it doesn't change the colour and I have no idea why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe setForeground is not the correct method to call

Comment: I'm not sure what other methods to try? setForeground seems to work elsewhere when I'm calling a constructor but when I try to use it to change the initial colours it doesn't work

Comment: @Cypher236 Take a look at my solution and let me know whether it solves you problem.

Comment: @Cypher236 I tried on my side, `setForeground()` is able to display all text in a different color. You may use `StyledDocument` if only you want specific text to change color.

Comment: @user3437460 Ok thanks I think I might have fixed it adapting your code slightly now - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting directly on the foreground property, you may want to do this:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();

Style style = textPane.addStyle("Blue", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.blue);
```

Comment: @Cypher236 Hmm, I see if I can write a mini demo on this.